# How to use string concatenations in ansible conditional checks?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to verify if a DNS record is matching ansible inventory but I get an error which doesn't not explain well the expected syntax.

```
- debug: msg="Update DNS for {{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when: "ec2_ip_address != lookup('ip', inventory_hostname + '.example.com')"
```

This piece of code returns this error:

```
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'ec2_ip_address != lookup('ip', inventory_hostname + '.example.com')' failed. The error was: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

The error appears to have been in 'some-playbook.yml': line 18, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - debug: msg=\"Update DNS for {{ inventory_hostname }}\"
      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - \"{{ foo }}\"
"}
```

Comment: which version of ansible (and what implementation of the ip lookup)?

Answer (score 0):

This reduced example works on ansible 2.1:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      ec2_ip_address: "www.example.com"
  - debug: msg="Update DNS for {{ inventory_hostname }}"
    when: ec2_ip_address != lookup('dig', inventory_hostname + '.example.com')
```

I am using the default `dig` dns lookup plugin